# How can I put background color to Entity-Relationship diagram in PlantUML

Tags: diagram, erd, plantuml, entity-relationship

I'm currently using PlantUML to design my database's ERD. All's well, the diagram is complete, but I'm trying to add a background color to my entities, to dintinguish them in their respective schemas.

I'm thinking of a backgroung color for the entities, or maybe a colored rectangle that holds the entities within it.

I tried using `skinparam` with the name of the entity, with its alias...

```
skinparam entity {
  backgroundColor<<usr>> DarkOrchid
}
```

```
skinparam entity {
  backgroundColor<<User>> DarkOrchid
}
```

None of these work... Can anybody help?

Thanks

=========
EDIT

As requested, a small example:

```
'==========='
'auth schema'
entity "User" as usr {
  *id : number <<PK>>
  --
  password: varchar
  salt: varchar
  role: number <<FK>>
  last_login_at : datetime
  is_active : boolean
}

entity "User Role" as url {
  *id : number <<PK>>
  --
  name: varchar
  clearance_lvl: text
  is_active : boolean
}

'====================='
'personnel data schema'

entity "Professor" as prof {
  *id : number <<PK>>
  --
  name: varchar
  office: integer
  user_id: number <<FK>>
  wage: number
  last_login_at : datetime
  is_active : boolean
}

entity "Student" as stu {
  *id : number <<PK>>
  --
  name: varchar
  semester: text
  user_id: number <<FK>>
  specialization: text
  is_active : boolean
}

usr ||--o{ url
prof ||--|| usr
stu ||--|| usr
```

### This generates the following diagram:

[image: default diagram]

### And I want to see something like this:

[image: colored diagram]

### Or at least somthing like this:

[image: background rectangle diagram]

Comment: Can you please add a small complete example that shows your problem?

Comment: Added visual aids and the example diagram. Is it clear what I'm looking for here? I thought this would have a simple solution, but I'm really struggling haha   Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `entity` object uses the skinparams of `class` ! So, you would have to say `skinparam class` instead of `skinparam entity` to change the background color of your entities.

To apply a certain background color to a selection of entities, you would have to add a stereotype to them so that they can be identified by the `skinparam class` command. For example, you could add `<<personnel>>` to the `Professor` and `Student` entities and `BackgroundColor<<personnel>>` to `skinparam class`.

This should fulfill the requirements of your first example:

```
skinparam  class {
    BackgroundColor<<personnel>> #A9DCDF
}


'==========='
'auth schema'
entity "User" as usr {
  *id : number <<PK>>
  --
  password: varchar
  salt: varchar
  role: number <<FK>>
  last_login_at : datetime
  is_active : boolean
}

entity "User Role" as url {
  *id : number <<PK>>
  --
  name: varchar
  clearance_lvl: text
  is_active : boolean
}

'====================='
'personnel data schema'

entity "Professor" as prof <<personnel>> {
  *id : number <<PK>>
  --
  name: varchar
  office: integer
  user_id: number <<FK>>
  wage: number
  last_login_at : datetime
  is_active : boolean
}

entity "Student" as stu <<personnel>> {
  *id : number <<PK>>
  --
  name: varchar
  semester: text
  user_id: number <<FK>>
  specialization: text
  is_active : boolean
}

usr ||--o{ url
prof ||--|| usr
stu ||--|| usr
```

To implement your second example, you could wrap your entities into packages and apply a different background directly as part of the `package` statement.

```
'==========='
'auth schema'
package "auth schema" #B4A7E5 {
entity "User" as usr {
}

entity "User Role" as url {
}
}

'====================='
'personnel data schema'
package "personnel data schema" #A9DCDF {
entity "Professor" as prof <<person>> {
}

entity "Student" as stu <<person>> {
}

usr ||--o{ url
prof ||--|| usr
stu ||--|| usr
```

Comment: Hum, ok, but the first approach changes the colors of all the entities.. I'd like to change only some, so is there a tag I can add on them to change only some? In my diagram, i have 2 entities with the light blue and 2 with the defaults yellowish... I want to change specific entities.. Can I create named classes of some sort, or change using ids?
I could use the package approach, but i cannot color them with different colors from each other, can I?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry, I had misunderstood your requirements. I have updated the answer to apply background colors to some entities (by using stereotypes) and adding colors directly in the packages statement (instead of with a skinparam statement).

Comment: Awesome, I tried using stereotypes using the entities names or aliases, and didn't define the stereotype in the actual entity. Thank you immensely!